# Class Cast Exception while trying to get kafka key in spring cloud

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am new in Kafka and Spring Cloud and I am sending message with a Key to a kafka topic and trying to read it by a listener. I am getting an exception while I am trying to get Kafka key in listener.

In the producer, I am writing to topic as below:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@EnableBinding(FirstStream.class)
public class FirstProducer {

    private final FirstStream firstStream;

    @Autowired
    public FirstProducer(FirstStream firstStream){
        this.firstStream= firstStream;
    }


    public void send(MyKey key, Record record) {
        log.info("Sending {}", record);
        MessageChannel messageChannel = firstStream.testOut();

        messageChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(record).setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, key).build());
    }
}
```

In the listener, I am catching message but later getting an exception:

```
   @StreamListener(FirstStream.INPUT)
    public void process(Message<?> message){

        Record record = (Record ) message.getPayload();   // here I get exception
        MyKey kafkaKey =  message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, MyKey.class);

        log.info("Received message");
        log.info("Processing:  {} ", record );

         ......
    }
```

> org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception thrown
>   while invoking rg.spring.adapters.MyProcessor#process[1 args]; nested
>   exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String
>   cannot be cast to class rg.spring.dto.raw.Record(java.lang.String is
>   in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; rg.spring.dto.raw.Record is
>   in unnamed module of loader 'app') ....
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot
>   be cast to class rg.spring.dto.raw.Record (java.lang.String is in
>   module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; rg.spring.dto.raw.Record is in
>   unnamed module of loader 'app')

Why I am getting this exception ? As I see payload is form of json string but it does not deserialize to the object instead, it throws classCastException.

I used:

> producer-properties:
>               key.serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
>               value.serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
>             consumer-properties:
>               key.deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
>               value.deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer

Comment: I used Json deserializer. I edited post.

Comment: Don't you have any further configuration for Producer and Consumer?